# Bot/command to display the contents of a Trello list?

Tags: trello, slack

I have a Trello board with a list named TODO. I'd like to have the contents of my TODO list sent to me every morning through Slack - either automatically or by running a command, which I could then automate using another integration/bot.

What's a good way to implement this?

So far I've looked into:

- [the Trello bot](https://slack.com/apps/A074YH40Z-trello) - allows you to display cards and boards, but not lists
- [Trello Alerts](https://slack.com/apps/A0F814C4R-trello-alerts) - can't be polled on demand
- [Workbot](https://slack.com/apps/A0HVDHQ8Z-workbot) - can only create Trello entities, not read them

Comment: I gave up on trello and started using the /todo app. Its one list per channel and not as "nice" as trello, but the trello slack integration is just unusable. Not to mention they dont acknowledge questions via /feedback or through support requests their own web site.